# Exception calling Access 2010 stored select query using OleDb.NET in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have created and saved a named query in an Access 2010 database with one parameter. However I cannot seem to be able to use it via VB.NET OleDb.

Here's the code I'm using (disregard the connection, which is set up correctly - it works using non-stored procedures)

```
Dim Command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Command.CommandText = "SelectUser"
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", "1234131")
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
```

This is the code of the stored procedure in Access 2010:

```
SELECT Users.*
FROM Users
WHERE Users.User_Id=[@UserId];
```

When executing the .NET code, I'm getting the following exception: 
*The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'SelectUser'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.*

What am I doing wrong, to me this make no sense.

Comment: You didn't post it, but make sure your Command object is actually using your Connection object.

Comment: @LarsTech: it is, as I said it works perfectly for non-stored queries, so the connection is fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the database that has the stored procedure?  You may have inadvertently added the stored procedure to the wrong database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected to the wrong copy of the database, a copy that did not contain the query.